# Does Sublime Xaml works for Windows Phone?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I installed https://github.com/maslbl4/sublime-xaml

but when I open a Windows Phone Xaml file nothing is highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on their page, [Sublime Xaml](https://github.com/maslbl4/sublime-xaml) has a lot of missing files to be called a library for Windows Phone.

Going deeper in the contents of the files you can easily read xml header

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```

Investigating a little will bring you to understand that this repository is for iOS only, I can't say if it works since i'm not an iOS developer.

But to answer your question:

**No this library doesn't work in your Windows Phone Project** neither in a Windows 8 Project or something .NET

Comment: it's weird not a single person on the planet has made something for WP or Windows 8

Comment: @user310291 what do you mean by "something"